# Mongoid returning the wrong count of documents

Tags: ruby, mongoid, pagy

Mongoid 8.1.4 on latest MongoDB, I'm using pagy to paginate (which doesn't work out of the box, but can be fixed by overriding a method).

My overriding:

```
module PagyExtension
  module Mongoid
    def pagy_get_vars(collection, vars)
      vars[:count] = collection.count
      super
    end
  end
end

Pagy::Backend.prepend PagyExtension::Mongoid
```

(Mongoid doesn't like AR `count(:all)`)
Everything appears to work, just not counting.

A spec to simplify the problem:

```
context "when paginating" do
  let(:params) do
    {
      "page" => 1,
      "per_page" => 20,
      "state" => "created"
    }
  end
  let!(:documents) { create_list(:document, 25) }

  it "returns paginated documents" do
    expect(result.value[:records].to_a.count).to eq(20)
    expect(result.value[:records].count).to eq(20)
  end
end
```

First expectation passes (there are actually 20 documents in `records`, second one fails, the method count returns "25".
Extremely confused by this, I can inspect `result.value[:records]` and see there are 20 documents, I have no idea why count returns 25.

Comment: I believe your issue may be related to the fact that `collection` is the entire collection, so your override sets "count" to 25; however when you call `to_a` it utilizes the limit provided returning only 20. `pagy.count` is used in a few locations to show things like "Displaying items 41-60 of 324 in total" where 324 is the count. In this case I believe your confusion is simply related to the fact that the "count" for the entire collection is different then the "count" for the paginated collection.